# LINQ grouping multiple columns with nested collection

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am grouping a collection, by multiple columns. It is easy to group them if they are on this same level of nesting:

```
var groupedAirProducts = airproductsPerClient.GroupBy(ac => new
{
    ac.AirProduct.PassengerNameRecord,
    ac.AirProduct.Flights.First().MarketingAirlineCode,
    ac.AirProduct.Flights.First().FlightNo,
    ac.AirProduct.Flights.First().DepartureDate
})
```

The problem is that I don't want only to group by a first flight, but I want to include all the flights. What I would like to do is something like:

```
var groupedAirProducts= airproductsPerClient.GroupBy(ac =>
{
    ac.AirProduct.PassengerNameRecord,
    foreach(var flight in ac.AirProduct.Flights){
        flight.MarketingAirlineCode,
        flight.FlightNo,
        flight.DepartureDate
    }
})
```

Please note that the code above is just an illustration of an idea. It is not a working/proper code. The only way I know how to do it is pretty ugly and complex. I was wondering if there is a nice way to do it using LINQ, or a simple way to tackle this problem.

Edit:
To explain more of what is expected. As a result of grouping I want to have collections of airProducts that share same PassengerNameRecord, and that flights that belong to a given air product share same MarketingAirlineCode, FlightNo, DepartureDate. I know how to implement it by flattering a collection of PassengerNameRecord, so the Flights are included in it, grouping it, so I have a groups of air products that share grouped properties. And then rebuilding the flattered structure. I was hoping that there is a way to either add groupBy properties by iterating thru some collection, or there is a way to merge grouped collection - if there is a way to have a collection grouped by PassengerNameRecord, and collection grouped by Flight properties and merging them together, unfortunately I doubt that there is an easy way to do such merge.

Comment: The "easy to group"-part doesn't compile. You need to use an anonymous type.

Comment: So basically you want to group by a collection (+ the `PassengerNameRecord`)?  Create a class which implements `IEqualityComparer<T>` with a proper `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. `T` is the type of a single `airproductsPerClient`.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand how grouping works - it should put any given entity into a single group. In your example, given multiple flights, you might end up with multiple groups to which the same entity should be assigned - this is no longer grouping (and therefore you might want to provide some more info on how this should work).

Comment: decPL: maybe there is no way to do it with a groupBy statement, and I have to introduce some layer of an abstraction - flattening the structure, or introducing new properties, in order to achieve my goal. This is why I am asking this question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement a custom `IEqualityComparer<AirClient>` for `GroupBy`(or other LINQ methods).

You can implement it in the following way:

```
public class AirClientComparer : IEqualityComparer<AirClient>
{
    public bool Equals(AirClient lhs, AirClient rhs)
    {
        if (lhs == null || rhs == null) return false;
        if(object.ReferenceEquals(lhs, rhs)) return true;
        if(lhs.PassengerNameRecord != rhs.PassengerNameRecord) return false;
        if(object.ReferenceEquals(lhs.AirProduct, rhs.AirProduct)) return true;
        if(lhs.AirProduct == null || rhs.AirProduct == null) return false;
        if(object.ReferenceEquals(lhs.AirProduct.Flights , rhs.AirProduct.Flights )) return true;
        if(lhs.AirProduct.Flights.Count !=  rhs.AirProduct.Flights.Count) return false;
        if(lhs.AirProduct.Flights.Count == 0 && rhs.AirProduct.Flights.Count == 0) return true;
        return lhs.AirProduct.Flights.All(f =>
            rhs.AirProduct.Flights.Any(f2 =>
                    f.MarketingAirlineCode == f2.MarketingAirlineCode
                 && f.FlightNo == f2.FlightNo
                 && f.DepartureDate == f2.DepartureDate));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(AirClient obj)
    {
        if(obj.AirProduct == null) return 0;
        int hash = obj.AirProduct.PassengerNameRecord == null 
                  ? 17 : 17 * obj.AirProduct.PassengerNameRecord.GetHashCode();
        unchecked
        {
            foreach(var flight in obj.AirProduct.Flights)
            {
                hash = (hash * 31) + flight.MarketingAirlineCode == null ? 0 : flight.MarketingAirlineCode.GetHashCode();
                hash = (hash * 31) + flight.FlightNo == null ? 0 : flight.FlightNo.GetHashCode();
                hash = (hash * 31) + flight.DepartureDate.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
       return hash;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it for example in `GroupBy`:

```
var groupedAirProducts = airproductsPerClient.GroupBy(ac => new AirClientComparer());
```

Comment: This is really nice way of tackling the problem. Thanks a million for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you need to start with the inner table.
The inner table also needs a reference to the outer table, such like you have a

`ICollection<Flight> Flights` in `AirProduct`

you also need a `Airproduct` Member inside of `Flight`.

Then group your flights like this (pseudo code)

```
AirProduct.Flights.groupby( flight => new{ flight.MarketingAirlineCode,
        flight.FlightNo,
        flight.DepartureDate,
        flight.product.PassengerNameRecord
});
```